# Redirect all 404 pages to home page in prestashop

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404, prestashop

How do i redirect all my 404 pages to home page in prestashop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From a UX perspective, I would strongly recommend you don't do that.  User's are more likely to believe that the redirect was accidental than deliberate and thus query the page again.

Answer (score 2):

For PS 1.5

controllers/front/PageNotFoundController.php

Add simple redirect to home page.

```
public function __construct()
{
    Tools::redirect(_PS_BASE_URL_);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your .htaccess file :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In /override/controllers/front/
create a file called: PageNotFoundController.php

we enter:

```
class PageNotFoundController extends PageNotFoundControllerCore
    {

    public function initContent()
    {
        Tools::redirect(_PS_BASE_URI_);
        exit;
     }
}
```

delete cache/class_index.php